# Validation Rule IF A Specific Picklist Value is Selected

Tags: validation, picklist, leads, validation-rule

I am trying to make a validation rule on Lead that will be for one profile and one role. The rule says that if the specific picklist value is selected and if one field in empty and then it should validate. Here is what I have come up with

```
AND( 
$UserRole.Name = 'Career Advisor - Inbound' , 
$Profile.Name = 'Acquire Sales Admin - Inbound', 
AND 
  (ISPICKVAL(Lead_Sources_for_Career_Advisor__c, 'Career One'),
   ISBLANK(Lead_Source_Referral__c)
  ) 
)
```

The problem is that the rule is not working. I can't figure out the reason for it. Any suggestions will be highly appriciated.

Thanks guys

Comment: Validation rules, if they return TRUE, throw the validation error. What did you mean by 'it should validate' ? You can examine the debug log to see what values are passed to the Validation Rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return a validation error on a record that does not comply with your rules then you should wrap it inside an IF clause like this.

```
IF(
AND( 
$UserRole.Name == 'Career Advisor - Inbound', 
$Profile.Name == 'Acquire Sales Admin - Inbound',
AND(
ISPICKVAL(Lead_Sources_for_Career_Advisor__c, 'Career One'),
ISBLANK(Lead_Source_Referral__c)
)
), false, true)
```

This will give an error when this formula is not met.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
AND( 
$UserRole.Name = 'Career Advisor - Inbound' , 
$Profile.Name = 'Acquire Sales Admin - Inbound', 
TEXT(Lead_Sources_for_Career_Advisor__c) == 'Career One',
ISBLANK(Lead_Source_Referral__c)
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually "Lead_Sources_for_Career_Advisor__c" is a picklist and i want to select "Career One" as a picklist value from it

Comment: try to just change the == by !=

Comment: hi Brovasi, it is still saving the record